# Reveal current file in project sidebar pane in Qt Creator

Tags: qt-creator

After using Sublime Text for a while for work, I've found myself wanting this feature more and more in Qt Creator. For those that don't know, in Sublime there is an option to open the project tree to the current file called "Reveal in sidebar".

Is there a keyboard shortcut for Qt Creator that I'm missing here? Or is the functionality simply not there?

Thank you for any light you can shed on the situation!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Look at the toolbar in Qt Creator, above the "Project" tree. You'll see a little button with two overlapped ovals. This will sync the project tree with the current open file, and reveal wherever it is in the project hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Just found this myself - it's a life-saver. I guess you're supposed to just know that two overlapped ovals means "Reveal in Project Tree".

Comment: Damned ovals! Who would have guessed that?! :) I actually suspect, this was on by default in earlier Creators, btw, as I never had to click any freakiy ovals before.